# For loop warning in R: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Here is my code and I am wondering why there are warning messages saying "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

```
for (i in 1:5) { 

if (i==1) {
Julian_data_first_expose[i]<-as.Date("2017-05-15") 
 }else{
Julian_data_first_expose[i]<-Julian_data_first_expose+365*(i-1)
 }
}
```

It seems work but I am curious about the warning messages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may lie in `Julian_data_first_expose+365*(i-1)`. This appears to return a vector, not a single value, is that what you intended? My guess at your intended code is `Julian_data_first_expose[i] +365*(i-1)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, my code should be `Julian_data_first_expose[i-1]+365*(i-1)`.